# pandas columns from another DataFrame if value is in another column?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have pd.DataFrame listing wire gauges and their corresponding currents:

e_ref =

```
   wire_gauge  current
0          14       15
1          12       20
2          10       30
3           8       50
4           6       60
5           4       85
6           3      100
7           2      115
```

Another DataFrame lists breakers in a system:

system =

```
    breakers
0         30
1         20
2         30
3         15
4         30
```

I need to add a "wire gauge" column to the system DataFrame from the "wire_gauge" columns of the e_ref DataFrame by looking up the breaker value in the current series of the e_ref.

so the output would be:

```
    breakers  wire_gauge
0         30  10
1         20  12
2         30  10
3         15  14
4         30  10
```

---

I keep confusing several answers from other post and currently do not have a working pandas solution.  I can get this working using python loops but I feel like there is a pandas one liner here...

Below are the types of solutions I'm working on:

```
df.ix[df.breakers.isin(e_ref['current']), 'wire_gauge'] = e_ref['wire_gauge']
```

and

```
df['wire_gauge']=e_ref.loc[e_ref['current'] == df['breakers'] ]
```

Thanks for your time and direction!

Answer (score 2):

Use [`map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.map.html) by `Series` created form `e_ref` or [`join`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.join.html), but is necessary values in `current`column in `e_ref` has to be unique:

```
print (e_ref['current'].is_unique)
True

s = e_ref.set_index('current')['wire_gauge']
system['wire_gauge'] = system['breakers'].map(s)
print (system)
   breakers  wire_gauge
0        30          10
1        20          12
2        30          10
3        15          14
4        30          10
```

Alternative:

```
df = system.join(e_ref.set_index('current'), on='breakers')
print (df)
   breakers  wire_gauge
0        30          10
1        20          12
2        30          10
3        15          14
4        30          10
```

Comment: I appreciate the options here.  Both return "nan" when I change the breaker value to 10 (seems to work for all other currents).  Otherwise this looks good.  I'll dig in more before I accept.

Comment: I think there is problem with different dtypes, check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/44001535/2901002)