# Pandas: Inner Join returns no rows

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

DataFrame 1 (`commits`)

```
CommitID  | COMMITTER  
------------------------
  1       | A         
  2       | B         
  3       | B
```

DataFrame 2 (`files`)

```
CommitID  | MOD
------------------------
  1       | 0         
  2       | 1         
  3       | 7
```

I tried to inner join these DataFrames with `df.merge`:

`files.merge(right=commits, how='inner',left_on="CommitID", right_on="CommitID")`

But it doesn't return any rows, although the column name is identical.

Comment: Have you tried this? - `left_index=True, right_index=True` ... Assuming CommitID is index in both dfs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is problem different `dtypes` of column `CommitID`.

Need check them by:

```
print (files['CommitID'].dtypes)
print (commits['CommitID'].dtypes)
```

And then convert by `astype` to same:

```
#change only object
files['CommitID'] = files['CommitID'].astype(int)
commits['CommitID'] = commits['CommitID'].astype(int)
```

---

```
#change only int
files['CommitID'] = files['CommitID'].astype(str)
commits['CommitID'] = commits['CommitID'].astype(str)
```

Yur code can be simplify - omit default `how='inner` and use only `on`:

```
df = files.merge(right=commits, on="CommitID")
print (df)
   CommitID  MOD COMMITTER
0         1    0         A
1         2    1         B
2         3    7         B
```

Or if only same joined columns in both `DataFrames`:

```
df = files.merge(right=commits)
print (df)
   CommitID  MOD COMMITTER
0         1    0         A
1         2    1         B
2         3    7         B
```