# Pandas merge of same datatypes returns NaN

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, jupyter-notebook

I am trying to merge two data frames on a similar column `commit_id`. However, they do not merge even after checking the datatypes to make sure they are the same.

My first dataframe is `df1` which contains two columns: `commit_id` and `final_sentiment`. My second dataframe is `df2` which contains two columns: `commit_id` and `modification`.

I am trying to merge into `df3` which would contain `commit_id`, `modification`, and `final_sentiment`. However, if I do a left join on `df2`, all the values in `final_sentiment` are `NaN`. If I do a right join, all the values in `modification` are `NaN`. I have checked the type of `commit_id` and it is object. Based on this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46754398/pandas-merge-returns-nan) and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44001525/pandas-inner-join-returns-no-rows), I tried to do change the type to string as such, before merging the data frames, but it did not work.

```
df1.commit_id = df1.commit_id.astype(str)
df2.commit_id = df2.commit_id.astype(str)
```

**EDIT: here is a more condensed version of the data to hopefully clear up the question.**

I have `df1`:

```
|  index | commit_id                                | final_sentiment |
|--------|------------------------------------------|-----------------|
| 807303 | 000e3673387b662e32f1037eeaea2aa29b630448 | -1              |
```

and I have `df2`:

```
|   | commit_id                                | modification |
|---|------------------------------------------|--------------|
| 0 | 000e3673387b662e32f1037eeaea2aa29b630448 | 13           |
```

`df1.info()` returns:

```
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
Int64Index: 1 entries, 807303 to 807303
Data columns (total 2 columns):
commit_id          1 non-null object
final_sentiment    1 non-null int64
dtypes: int64(1), object(1)
memory usage: 24.0+ bytes
```

df2.info() returns:

```
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 1 entries, 0 to 0
Data columns (total 2 columns):
commit_id       1 non-null object
modification    1 non-null int64
dtypes: int64(1), object(1)
memory usage: 88.0+ bytes
```

As you can see they are the same type for commit id, yet when I merge, it still returns NaN:

```py
df3 = df2.merge(df1, on='commit_id', how='left')
df3
```

df3 returns:

```
|   | commit_id                                | modification | final_sentiment |
|---|------------------------------------------|--------------|-----------------|
| 0 | 000e3673387b662e32f1037eeaea2aa29b630448 | 13           | NaN             |
```

it should return:

```
|   | commit_id                                | modification | final_sentiment |
|---|------------------------------------------|--------------|-----------------|
| 0 | 000e3673387b662e32f1037eeaea2aa29b630448 | 13           | -1              |
```

Sorry, for the bad formatting. Jupyter notebook formatting isn't so nice on stackoverflow.

As you can see, I check the types of both dataframes and they are same. I show both an inner join and left join. The inner join, returns no result, but the left join returns result as it should, but the final mod is NaN.

How can I get it that the dataframes merge correctly, I am not sure what is going wrong here?

Comment: I feel there is too much info here. you will get more attention if you can create a sample df(refer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples) ) and expected output, a peice of code you have tried and a brief explaination. Make sure every thing is short and covers your case. :)

Comment: @anky_91 the problem with creating a test case is that it works. But with this data, it doesn't work. Let me get rid of some rows and create a smaller edit to show hopefully show more clearly. I was also trying to encapsulate all my previous attempts at fixing the issue.

Comment: exactly, so if we assume and create an answer, it wont work. Rather create a test case which covers all cases. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the solution in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52444020/11376375). There was a blank character, so the data wasn't matching. Using `str.strip()` fixed the issue for me.