# Group DataFrame, apply function with inputs then add result back to original

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

Can't find this question anywhere, so just try here instead:

What I'm trying to do is basically alter an existing DataFrame object using groupby-functionality, and a self-written function:

```
benchmark =

x    y    z    field_1

1    1    3    a
1    2    5    b
9    2    4    a
1    2    5    c
4    6    1    c
```

What I want to do, is to groupby `field_1`, apply a function using specific columns as input, in this case columns `x` and `y`, then add back the result to the original DataFrame `benchmark` as a new column called `new_field`. The function itself is dependent on the value in `field_1`, i.e. `field_1=a` will yield a different result compared to `field_1=b` etc. (hence the grouping to start with).

Pseudo-code would be something like:

```
1. grouped_data = benchmark.groupby(['field_1'])
2. apply own_function to grouped_data; with inputs ('x', 'y', grouped_data)
3. add back result from function to benchmark as column 'new_field'
```

Thanks,

### ALTERATION:

```
benchmark =

x    y    z    field_1

1    1    3    a
1    2    5    b
9    2    4    a
1    2    5    c
4    6    1    c
```

Elaboration:

I also have a DataFrame `separate_data` containing separate values for `x`,

```
separate_data =

x    a    b    c

1    1    3    7
2    2    5    6
3    2    4    4
4    2    5    9
5    6    1    10
```

that will need to be interpolated onto the existing `benchmark` DataFrame. Which column in `separate_data` that should be used for interpolation *is dependent on* column `field_1` in `benchmark` (i.e. values in set `(a,b,c)` above). The interpolated value in the new column, is based on x-value in `benchmark`.

Result:

benchmark =

```
x    y    z    field_1  field_new

1    1    3    a        interpolate using separate_data with x=1 and col=a
1    2    5    b        interpolate using separate_data with x=1 and col=b
9    2    4    a        ... etc
1    2    5    c        ...
4    6    1    c        ...
```

Makes sense?

Comment: I edit solution, it seems `groupby` is not necessary, only `join`. Can you check it and if some problem, let me know? thanks.

Comment: Thanks @jezrael. The solution you gave solved my problem somewhat, but was not exactly what I was looking for. However, as my question is so vague, I'll have to accept it! Thanks again

Answer (score 3, accepted):

EDIT:

I think you need reshape `separate_data` first by [`set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) + [`stack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html), set index names by [`rename_axis`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.rename_axis.html) and set name of `Serie` by rename.

Then is possible `groupby` by both levels and use some function.

Then [`join`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.join.html) it to `benchmark` with default left join:

```
separate_data1 =separate_data.set_index('x').stack().rename_axis(('x','field_1')).rename('d')
print (separate_data1)
x  field_1
1  a           1
   b           3
   c           7
2  a           2
   b           5
   c           6
3  a           2
   b           4
   c           4
4  a           2
   b           5
   c           9
5  a           6
   b           1
   c          10
Name: d, dtype: int64
```

If necessary use some function, mainly if some duplicates in pairs `x` with `field_1` it return nice unique pairs:

```
def func(x):
    #sample function   
    return x / 2 + x ** 2


separate_data1 = separate_data1.groupby(level=['x','field_1']).apply(func)
print (separate_data1)
x  field_1
1  a            1.5
   b           10.5
   c           52.5
2  a            5.0
   b           27.5
   c           39.0
3  a            5.0
   b           18.0
   c           18.0
4  a            5.0
   b           27.5
   c           85.5
5  a           39.0
   b            1.5
   c          105.0
Name: d, dtype: float64


benchmark = benchmark.join(separate_data1, on=['x','field_1'])
print (benchmark)

   x  y  z field_1     d
0  1  1  3       a   1.5
1  1  2  5       b  10.5
2  9  2  4       a   NaN
3  1  2  5       c  52.5
4  4  6  1       c  85.5
```

---

I think you cannot use `transform` because multiple columns which are read together.

So use [`apply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.apply.html):

```
df1 = benchmark.groupby(['field_1']).apply(func)
```

And then for new column are multiple solutions, e.g. use [`join`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.join.html) (default `left join`) or [`map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.map.html).

Sample solution with both method is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43979558/2901002).

Or is possible use [flexible apply](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/groupby.html#flexible-apply) which can return new `DataFrame` with new column.

Comment: sorry you are right. deleted my comment to avoid confusion

Comment: No problem. Nice day!

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```
groups = benchmark.groupby(benchmark["field_1"])    
benchmark = benchmark.join(groups.apply(your_function), on="field_1")
```

In your_function you would create the new column using the other columns that you need, e.g. average them, sum them, etc.

Documentation for [apply](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html).
Documentation for [join](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.join.html).

Answer (score 0):

Here is a working example:

```
# Sample function that sums x and y, then append the field as string.
def func(x, y, z):
    return (x + y).astype(str) + z

benchmark['new_field'] = benchmark.groupby('field_1')\
                                  .apply(lambda x: func(x['x'], x['y'], x['field_1']))\
                                  .reset_index(level = 0, drop = True)
```

Result:

```
benchmark
Out[139]: 
   x  y  z field_1 new_field
0  1  1  3       a        2a
1  1  2  5       b        3b
2  9  2  4       a       11a
3  1  2  5       c        3c
4  4  6  1       c       10c
```